# Datomic exceed GC overhead limit

Tags: garbage-collection, datomic

Trying to count entities in datomic with this query

```
(d/q '[:find (count ?a) . :where [?a :type]] (d/db (conn)))

OutOfMemoryError GC overhead limit exceeded  [trace missing]
```

Working thought if I try to count smaller subset like

```
(d/q '[:find (count ?a) :where [?a :type "psp"]] (d/db (conn)))

[[400541]]
```

Using dev backend.

Is it me doing something wrong, or should I try different backend, or something else?

Here is stacktrace http://pastebin.com/C76mEhEJ which leads somewhere inside `datomic.datalog`.

Comment: What are your heap settings? This look like you don't have enough memory for the intermediate representation (still a set of tuples, despite your aggregating over it).

Comment: @BenKamphaus If I undersnand jvm options correctly, my initial and max heap sizes are 2Gb and 4Gb here is jvm output http://pastebin.com/eRpEXEuv, tried to run with "-Xmx6g" "-Xms4g", same result and that is almost all ram I have. Btw, what do you mean by intermediate result, that `?a` (whole dataset) in my case?

Comment: yes, query in Datomic is eager and aggregates in query operate on all tuples that match [_ :type _ _ _] for your case. you might try a lazy seq operation for a db scan with datoms, something like: `(count (dedupe (map #(:e %) (seq (d/datoms (d/db conn) :aevt :type)))))`

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks, I should probably read more about datomic.

Comment: Glad that approach worked, I converted my comment to an answer with more details now that I've verified my understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query in Datomic is eager. Even when using aggregates, the entire intermediate representation will be realized. In your case, this is the collection of all tuples for the entity-id, type, value portion for all entities in your database. You will see errors like this when the entire intermediate set can't be realized in memory, but the structure of your query isn't one on which Datomic can naively tell there will be a database scan (in those cases it will throw).

If you're scanning the entire database, `datoms` - documented [here](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/datoms) - is a better fit as it will lazily traverse all datoms that match a prefix. A lazy seq approach for a db scan with `datoms` for your use case could be something like:

```
(count (dedupe (map #(:e %) (seq (d/datoms (d/db conn) :aevt :type)))))
```

This gets all datoms from the `:aevt` index that have the attribute `:type` (the attribute is then a leading component that narrows the results). We deal with `datoms` output as a `seq`, and get the `:e` (entity id) from each datom, deduping so we only count unique entities. You could possibly avoid this `dedupe` step if this is a cardinality one attribute.